# Creating a three row layout

Tags: css

I'm currently in the process of creating a three row layout, nothing too difficult so far. The problem arises because I need each row to be 100% width to fill any resolution with a color and I also need the divs inside each row to be 1024/960px and centered.

Something along these lines:

```
<div class="top"> <!--This needs to be 100%-->
    <div class="logo-holder"></div> <!--This needs to be 1024px centered-->
    <div class="menu-holder"></div> <!--This needs to be 1024px centered-->
</div>
<div class="main"> <!--This needs to be 100%-->
    <div class="rotating-banner"></div> <!--This needs to be 1024px centered-->
    <div class="promo-holder"> <!--This needs to be 1024px centered-->
        <div class="promo-banner"></div>
        <div class="games-list"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"> <!--This needs to be 100%-->
    <div class="footer-holder"></div> <!--This needs to be 1024px centered-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.top, .main, .footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo-holder, .menu-holder, .rotating-banner, .promo-holder, .footer-holder {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

should do it.

Comment: Tnks a lot, was trying with: "margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" and obviously wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

by default the divs will take up 100% width, as they are block level elements.

on the classes for top,main,footer add `margin:0px auto;` for the divs inside those, add your width.

This may not center in ie, so also add `text-align:center;` and then in the inner divs add `text-align:left;`

Answer (score 0):

```
.top { width:100%; margin:0 auto; }
.logo-holder,  .menu-holder {width:1024px; margin:0 auto }
```

But you should use IDs for holders & other unique wrapper elements.